# Query to get the result in between epoch_timestamp

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where I have company_id and epoch_timestamp when they accessed. When I am running a query to get the result in between two timestamps I am not getting the result. Its showing 0 result but the result lies in between in Postressql db

My query is:

```
select company_id, count(company_id) AS count from tblhistorymaster 
WHERE user_last_request_time BETWEEN 1586197800000 AND 1614277799999
group by company_id

select company_id, count(company_id) AS count from tblhistorymaster 
WHERE user_last_request_time >= 1586197800000    AND user_last_request_time < 1614277799999
group by company_id
```

Any suggestion will be of great help.

Comment: `1586197800000` is not a timestamp. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Comment: If that query doesn't return anything, then obviously you have no rows that satisfy the condition.

Comment: Check if the `tblhistorymaster` table has another column for the regular timestamp. From there, you could extract the epoch from it and then use it in the filter. See the official docs - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have checked in this website epoch timestamp is correct `https://www.epochconverter.com/`

Comment: @etch_45 It has only epoch_timestamp

Comment: That might be, but `1586197800000` still is a number, not a [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) - but I do believe Postgres more than you. There simply isn't data in your table that matches your WHERE condition. You might _think_ there is, but the fact that you get no results means there isn't

Comment: Is your epoch stored in seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: Try `select to_timestamp( ... )` and put the epoch value in there to see what is the output, that would be the actual timestamp if it is valid. The docs I linked has the example of its use.

Comment: I have found the problem when I trimmed by epoch value to first 10 digit then I am getting the result

Comment: And that's precisely the reason why using a proper `timestamp` (or `timestamptz`) to store this in the database is the better choice.